# Enhanced Caesar Cipher

Tags: c#

This cipher takes a byte array and applies a relatively 'random' offset for each byte. In order to keep track of the offsets, to allow the encryption to be reversed, I decided against maintaining a list of offsets, like the old school one-time pads, and went with using the first byte of the hash of the key, then rehashing the hash.  To increase the complexity of the encryption, I used the 1st bit of the second element of the hash, to set the direction of the offset.

The offsets aren't truly random, but the encrypted bytes of a 2mb text file, do pass all the tests in the NIST test suite

```
class Cipher
{

    private enum EncryptionMode
    {
        Encrypt = 1,
        Decrypt = -1
    }
    public static byte[] Encrypt(string key, byte[] data)
    {
        return DeEncrypt(key, data, EncryptionMode.Encrypt);
    }
    public static byte[] Decrypt(string key, byte[] data)
    {
        return DeEncrypt(key, data, EncryptionMode.Decrypt);
    }
    private static byte[] DeEncrypt(string key, byte[] data, EncryptionMode mode)
    {
        if(key == null)
        {
            key = "";
        }
        if(data == null)
        {
            data = new byte[] { 0 };
        }
        var temp = HashCode(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
        var newData = new byte[data.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
        {               
            newData[i] = GetNewValue(data[i], temp, mode);
            temp = HashCode(temp);
        }
        return newData;
    }
    private static byte[] HashCode(byte[] input)
    {
        var hash = Sha3.Sha3512().ComputeHash(input);
        return hash;
    }
    private static byte GetNewValue(byte value, byte[] hash, EncryptionMode mode)
    {
        //This determines the direction of the offset based on the 1st bit of the second byte in the hash
        //and switches it according to the encryption mode.
        var direction = (((hash[1] & 1) * 2) - 1) * (int)mode;
        var offset = hash[0] * direction;
        return (byte)ShiftMod256((ulong)(value + 256 + offset));
    }

    //Since only mod 256 is used I figured bit shifting would be better than division.
    public static ulong ShiftMod256(ulong num)
    {
        return (num << 56) >> 56;
    }

}
```